# Compute angle of vector in word2vec models

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, word-embeddings, word2vec, gensim, cosine-distance

If I understand correctly, the `most_similar` function computes the cosine similarity of the vector with all other vectors and finds the closest one.  The vectors then viewed from a certain origin of (0,0,0,..0) for N dimensions (for N dimensional word vectors).

Is there by any means that I could compute the angle of these vectors from the origin ?. 
If I compute the similarity between the vector and the origin vector and take the inverse cosine, will the resultant angle be the angle of the vector on origin space.

If I get such an angle, on which plane does it lie as the vector is high dimensional.

The reason is that, when we try to reduce it to 2 dimensions and plot them, only magnitude of the vector is considered right, so the direction information is missing. I would like to plot it in a polar plot to view both.

Is there any such function in `gensim`?.

Comment: An angle is defined relative to two rays starting at a common point. What's the other vector going through the origin here besides the one you are evaluating?

Comment: The origin vector with 0s at all positions. If you could compute the cosine distance between two vectors, why can't be a vector and an origin vector.

Comment: The problem is that Infinitely many vectors go through the origin. You need a second point for the vector to go through to uniquely identify it.

Comment: "when we try to reduce it to 2 dimensions": are you referring to some kind of PCA on the word vectors? If yes, your "direction information" would be preserved in the principal components.